# ¿porque este fragmento de codigo no se renderiza?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo este codigo escrito en ReactJS, lo que hace en resumen es sencillo, me conecta a una API, y en teoria, deberia renderizarlo, es decir, mostrarlo en el navegador. Estuve viendo durante horas cual podria ser el error, pero no lo encuentro, no puedo hacer que este codigo se renderize, como lo soluciono?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const TVShows = () => {
  const [ loadMovies, setLoadMovies] = useState(false)
  const [ movie, setMovie ] = useState({})
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    const apiMovies = `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?api_key=86d14782edf23&lenguage=es-MX`
    fetch(apiMovies)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then( movieRequest => {console.log(movieRequest.results)

      setMovie(movieRequest)
      setLoadMovies(true)
    })
  },[])

  return (<>`introducir el código aquí`
  {loadMovies ? movie.map( movie => {return <ul><li key={movie.id}>{movie.title}</li> </ul>}):'i'}  
      
    <input type='text' placeholder='Ingrese un texto'></input>

    {/* CARTAS */}
    <div id='carta'>
      
    </div>
  </>)
}
```

Comment: Oie como sugerencia, cuando coloques preguntas que incluyan APIs quita la URL y peor cuando tienen api_keys

Comment: ahi modifique el key, muchas gracias

Comment: Si te fue de ayuda la [publicacion pasada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/591177/101408) por favor vota para que se difunda y el proceso mejore, saludos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema esta en que movie es un objeto, no es un array.
El array se encuentra en movie.results.

Cambia

```
{loadMovies ? movie.map( movie => {return <ul><li key={movie.id}>{movie.title}</li> </ul>}):'i'}
```

a

```
{loadMovies ? movie.results.map( movie => {return <ul  key={movie.id}><li>{movie.title}</li> </ul>}):'i'}
```

Ademas te recomiendo que el atributo key lo cambies a la etiqueta padre del return. En este caso a la etiqueta `<ul key={movie.id}>`.

Comment: Me funciono, eres un genio!