# ¿Por que no puedo acceder a las propiedades con getStaticProps()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Estoy en next, intentando acceder a la propiedad de una api, lo unico que quiero es que se renderize mediante la la funcion de getStaticprops(), pero por alguna razon no puedo, a pesar de seguir la sintaxys correcta, que es lo que esta mal en este codigo?, solo quiero que se renderize:

```
export function ListOfPost({ data }) {
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.results.map((post) => {
        return (
          <li key={post.url}>
            <h4>{post.name}</h4>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  try {
    const resp = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151");
    const data = await resp.json();

    return {
      props: {
        data,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Como ven, solo quiero acceder a los nombres de los pokemons con el metodo .map (abajo dejo estructura de la api)

El error que me da esto es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la api que quiero consumir, pero mostrado en postman:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ACLARACION: si bien es tecnologia nextJS, considero que el problema es fundamentalmente de javascript, ya que el error esta apareciendo puntualmente en la linea 4:

> data.results.map, pareciera ser que resultado es undefined.

¿como soluciono este problema?

Comment: Primero verifica que esta llegando data al componente, da un console.log(data) debajo de esta linea `const data = await resp.json();` en `getStaticProps`, tambien hasta donde se `getStaticProps` va declarado antes del componente, en este caso antes de `ListOfPost`, empieza x ahi

Comment: intente lo que me dijiste pero en la consola no se muestra nada, por consola me refiero a la consola de visual studio code, ya que en el navegador con nextjs los mensajes por consolas no se suelen hacer mucho ya que muestran otras cosas

Comment: Ya verifique y de mi lado si funciona tal cual lo codificaste, muestra la configuracion del archivo next.config.js, que versión de nextJs etas usando?

Comment: segun mi package-lock.json es la version "next": "13.3.0", en consola lo instalo asi: npmx create-next-app@latest. Mi configuracion next.config.js es la siguiente: /** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig =  {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['raw.githubusercontent.com'],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es la versión de `nextJS`, en la `version 13` se puede leer:

> Previous Next.js (v 12) data fetching methods such as getServerSideProps, getStaticProps, and getInitialProps are not supported in the new app directory

Por lo tanto se esta tratando de usar patrones de la versión 12 en la versión 13, que ya estan obsoletos.

Ahora se hace directamente y se conoce como **colocated data fetching** al nivel del componente:

```
async function getData() {
  try {
    const resp = await fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=151");
    const data = await resp.json();

    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

export default async function ListOfPost() {
  const data = await getData();
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.results.map((post) => {
        return (
          <li key={post.url}>
            <h4>{post.name}</h4>
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Sugiero que te pases a nextJS 13

tutorial nextJS 13
https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/installation

Comment: Hola buenas, actualmente estoy usando la version 13.3.0, eso explicaria por que no me funciona, deberia usar la documentacion beta entonces?: https://beta.nextjs.org/docs

Comment: Parece que estas aprendiendo entonces puedes hacer ambos tutoriales v12 y v13 para que veas las diferencias (que son significativas)